# How can I make EditorFor use the HTML5 min and max attributes?

Tags: html, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

If I have an entity like this:

```
class Foo
{
    [Range(0,100)]
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

...and I use `EditorFor(m => m.Bar)` in an MVC view, it uses the HTML5 `<input type="number">` tag but *not* use the `min` and `max` attributes of that tag. Is there something I can do to make it use them?

Comment: Try using Html.TextBoxFor(...)

Comment: How would that help? That makes it *not* use the HTML5 `<input type="number">` tag.

Comment: Hrmm.. Well, it _does_ make the range work.

Comment: It "works" in the sense that the JavaScript or server-side validation works correctly, but that *already* worked. It does not "work" in relation to my question, which was about HTML5.

Comment: I'm interested in a solution to how `EditorFor` can be used, but you can accomplish this with `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.bar, new { type = "number", min = 0, max = 100 })`.  With this method, the validation will still respect the `Range` data attributes on the ViewModel.

Comment: So long as your using MVC-5.1 or higher, its `EditorFor(m => m.Bar, new { htmlAttributes = new { min = "0", max = "100" } })`, otherwise you have to use `TexBoxFor()` as noted by @alex

Comment: You can create a custom EditorFor template. See http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-display-templates-and-editor-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.htm for how to create custom templates.